# Visualforce page with unique URL?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

How is it possible to create a Visualforce page form that will have a unique URL, based on the Account this is going to be sent to?

Request is to send customer a form that is presented on the VS page, which after completion will feed the input to that customers Account.
Is such a thing possible?

Comment: I think https://instance/apex/VFPage?id=AccId might be unique URL based on the Account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include Account record id to the page. It will make URL unique for each unique account.
If the page is hosted on Salesforce side you can rewrite url using Site.UrlRewriter  class